# Nested list comprehension understanding for comparing strings in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

I have two lists

```
l1 = ["filea", "fileb", "filec"]
l2 = ["a", "b"]
```

I'd like to product a resulting list `l3` that contains the elements of l1 that contain an element of l2. So in the end I'd like to have

```
l3 = ["filea", "fileb"]
```

I just can't figure out how to do it with list comprehensions...
I tried :

```
l3 = [x for x in l1 for y in l2 if y in x]
```

and it works...

I would just like to understand what's really happening here and in which order. For any help I'd be super grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```py
l3 = [x for x in l1 for y in l2 if y in x]
```

It's equal to the following:

```py
l3 = []
for x in l1:  # loop through each element in the list l1
    for y in l2:  # loop through each element in the list l2
        if y in x: # if x contains y
            l3.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The same can be written as:

```
l3 = []
for x in l1:
    for y in l2:
        if y in x:
            l3.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply loop an all of the lists and check if there is an element in `l2` that are in `l1` elements

### Example

```
l1 = ["filea", "fileb", "filec"]
l2 = ["a", "b"]

l3 = list({x for x in l1 for y in l2 if x[-1] in l2})
# Or
l3 = [x for x in l1 for y in l2 if y in x]
print(l3)
```

### List comprehension breakdown

you just looped over `l1` and `l2` because in python you can index on string like you do on list and also you can check if one character is occur in whole string so is what you did on `if y in x` you checked if character `y` occurs in string `x`

```
l3 = []
for x in l1:
    for y in l2:
        if y in x:
            l3.append(x)
```

### Output

```
['filea', 'fileb']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
l3 = [s for s in l1 if any(c in s for c in l2)]
```

A more efficient solution is to use regular expressions:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, l2)))
l3 = list(filter(pattern.search, l1))   # Equivalent to [s for s in l1 if pattern.search(s)]
```